# Create DLL : How can I use a dll to create a new dll?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2005:
I want to create a dll base on another dll. 
For example : I want to create a DLL -- new.dll, and it uses a DLL -- old.dll;
How can I create a new.dll have old.dll inside? I mean, I don't need to include old.dll in my project when I use new.dll?

Thanks for any advisement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the source code of the old.dll? Is your dll .net dll?

The method about gac is for .net dll and is not for general dll.

If not .net dll, you need to build a library (.lib) first. And let your new.dll linked with the library.

Comment: kcwu
thanks.I did not have the source code of old.dll.
It is not a .net dll.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to register the dll in gac

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/ViewForum.aspx?ForumId=16430